# Chamar video do youtube com click para uma section responsiva com jquery

Tags: jquery, youtube

Gostaria de chamar vários vídeo do canal do YouTube para uma section, as chamadas seriam um por um, através de click, aos vários títulos correspondentes aos vídeo, ou pode ser também link.
grato.

```
    <ul>
    <li><a class="video-thumbnail" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_y7rKxqPoyg" title="Um título legal aqui">Vídeo 1</li>
    <li><a class="video-thumbnail" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCWkeFBCPnA" title="Outro título legal aqui">Vídeo 2</li>
    <li><a class="video-thumbnail" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VcF7SySRkHs" title="Mais um título legal aqui">Vídeo 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="video-placeholder">
    <iframe width="820" height="380" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_y7rKxqPoyg"></iframe>
</div>


function getVideoId (url) {
    var regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/,
         match = url.match(regExp);

    if (match && match[2].length === 11) {
        return match[2];
    } else {
        throw new Error("Invalid video URL");
    }
}

var videos      = document.querySelectorAll('.video-thumbnail'),
    placeholder = document.querySelector('.video-placeholder'),
    i, len;

for ( i = 0, len = videos.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    videos[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var videoUrl = getVideoId(this.getAttribute('href'));
        var title    = this.getAttribute('title');

        placeholder.innerHTML = '<iframe width="820" height="380" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoUrl + '"></iframe>';
        document.title = title;
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: E [o que você já tentou](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: Bem o que realmente tenho até agora, é um script em javascript, tentei fazer alguma mudanças, mas não cumpri com o desejado.

Comment: Poderia postar o código que você desenvolveu até agora?

Comment: Pronto @PauloHDSousa, o problema é que no script ele pela o elemento pelo getAttibute, como no sistema tem vários href, ele não considera, no exemplo acima ele consegui buscar o código e trazer pra div.